# three.js connected two moving parts with sphere

Tags: three.js

I'm trying visualize leg position with connected gyro/acelometers
one connected  below and second above knee

so I have 3 angles  for each one ( x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2 )

I can draw and rotate each one  independent, but have no idea how to connect them  with sphere( knee )

Position doesn't matter, only angles  valuable

I'm new with three.js and haven't even direction how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can add leg parts as children of the knee.
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.add

Alternatively you can merge geometries but you would lose independent angles https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.merge